# Yesod: access StaticR image from AuthR

Tags: haskell, yesod

So I have a widget for the a registration form in the Auth subsite:

```
customRegisterHandler = do
(widget, enctype) <- lift $ generateFormPost registrationForm
toParentRoute <- getRouteToParent
lift $ authLayout $ do
    setTitle "Reg"
    $(widgetFile "registrationpage")
```

But I need a logo (in StaticR) pointing to the homepage:

```
<a href="@{HomeR}">
    <img src='@{StaticR img_logo_name_png}'>

<form method="post" action="@{toParentRoute registerR}" enctype=#{enctype}>
    <div #registerForm .form-group>
        ^{widget}
    <button .btn .btn-success>Reg
```

That of course gives me a compiler error, how could I achieve that?

**Edit**, compiler error:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘master’ with ‘App’
  ‘master’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             customRegisterHandler :: (YesodAuthEmail master,
                                       YesodAuth master) =>
                                      HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master IO) Html
           at Foundation.hs:323:26
Expected type: WidgetT
                 master IO (Route App -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
  Actual type: WidgetT
                 master
                 IO
                 (Route (HandlerSite (WidgetT master IO)) -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
Relevant bindings include
  toParentRoute :: Route Auth -> Route master
    (bound at Foundation.hs:326:5)
  widget :: WidgetT master IO () (bound at Foundation.hs:325:6)
  customRegisterHandler :: HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master IO) Html
    (bound at Foundation.hs:324:1)
In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘getUrlRenderParams’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  (getUrlRenderParams
   >>=
     (\ urender_aQgm
        -> (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
             (toHtml (\ u_aQgn -> urender_aQgm u_aQgn [] HomeR))))
```

Comment: What's the compiler error ?

Comment: Oops, added to the question @Sibi

Comment: `registerR` doesn't seem to correspond to convention. Is it handler?
Is there `RegisterR`?

Comment: I have to use `registerR`, otherwise:     Not in scope: data constructor ‘RegisterR’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘Register’ (imported from Yesod.Auth.Message),
      variable ‘registerR’ (imported from Yesod.Auth.Email)
    In the splice: $(widgetFile "registrationpage")

Comment: But well.. that works anyways, the problem is the StaticR reference

Comment: Hmm, I can't quite decipher the type error. The problem should not be in using `StaticR`, since then `HomeR` should also give an error. I just tried referring to it in my own custom register handler and it works fine. One thing though, you might need to do `touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs` to make it pick up new static files.

Comment: Also, how is your `registrationForm` form defined? It might be the case that you are returning `(userRes, widget)` instead of `return (userRes, widget)`, with the former case not working.